# Why doesn't my OpenGL ES view update when using the following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I am programming an OpenGL game for the iPhone, and have this code that is called 24 times a second, meant to update the view:

```
[gameWorld update];

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.85f, 0.35f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
    glVertex3f(gameWorld.player.x, gameWorld.player.y, 0);
    glVertex3f(gameWorld.player.x+10, gameWorld.player.y, 0);
    glVertex3f(gameWorld.player.x+10, gameWorld.player.y+20, 0);
    glVertex3f(gameWorld.player.x, gameWorld.player.y+20, 0);
}
glEnd();
```

Where [gameWorld update] calls the code necessary to change the gameWorld.player.x based on what key is pressed (this works). My problem is that the yellow rectangle drawn on the screen doesn't move after the glBegin() block. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glBegin()/glEnd() is not supported on OpenGL ES 1.1.

You might want to take a look at [this post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/nehe-tutorials-lesson-2-ported-to.html) which explains how to perform similar operations. Basically, for drawing a triangle:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, triVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Comment: That works, but now the drawn object wont move. The gameWorld.player.x changes, but the location of the rectangle on the screen doesn't.

Comment: @Jumhyn - Have you updated the vertices within `triVertices` to reflect the change in the coordinates of your object?

Comment: I changed triVertices to quadVertices since I'm drawing a rectangle, but it looks like this: 
 GLfloat quadVertices[] = { 
  gameWorld.player.x, gameWorld.player.y, 0, 
  gameWorld.player.x+10, gameWorld.player.y, 0, 
  gameWorld.player.x+10, gameWorld.player.y+20, 0,
  gameWorld.player.x, gameWorld.player.y+20, 0
 }; 


EDIT: Poor formatting in comments, hope its still readable.

Comment: Hummm... Are you sure you did not declare the GLfloat array as static? You could also take a look at glTranslatef() (on GL_MODELVIEW matrix) to move your quad without modifying the vertices...

Comment: @Ozirus How would I do that? I'm completely new to OpenGL.

Comment: @Jumhyn - Create a new application in Xcode from the OpenGL ES template.  By default, it just animates a square up and down on the screen.  If you look at the OpenGL ES 1.1 section of the code, it shows how to use `glTranslatef()` to move objects.